# how to join two different tables in mysql,with no fields common?

Tags: php, mysql, database

eg:
this is table_1

### car

```
bmw
benz
honda
```

this is table_2

### colour

```
blue
red
brown
```

expected is table_3

```
cars   colour
----   -----
bmw     blue
benz    red
honda   brown
```

Comment: Do you want to have the first row of the first table to match the first row of the second table?

Comment: Obviously you haven't understood what 'join' is meant for. First paragraph in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: not needed. just simply need to join them.... and later apply count... anyways just want to know to join... thanks!

Comment: @mrt :so what operation do i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you need to invent some sort of joining column. Variables can be used for that:

```
select q1.name as car, q2.name as colour 
from
  (select @row := @row + 1 as r, name from car, (select @row := 0) q) q1
inner join
  (select @row2 := @row2 + 1 as r, name from colour, (select @row2 := 0) q) q2
on q1.r = q2.r;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7d46/7

Note: this seems like a strange task that has no real value.

Comment: @saurabh no problems. if it meets your requirements could you please mark the answer as accepted